# Не могу выбрать строку SQLite по двум параметрам

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

необходимо выбрать строку, которая будет удовлетворять двум условиям. Пробовал сделать так:

```
cursor.execute(
                """SELECT id FROM nat WHERE city = {city} AND sex = {sex} ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1""".format(city=city_, sex=sex_))
```

но выдает ошибку синтаксиса. Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше делать через биндинг параметров:

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM nat WHERE city = ? AND sex = ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
cursor.execute(sql, (city, sex_))
```

В качестве бонуса получите защиту от [sql-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

```
"""SELECT id FROM nat WHERE city = '{city}' AND sex = '{sex}' ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: А если в `city` будет присутствовать `'`, то снова получится ошибка синтаксиса, верно?

Comment: @gil9red и это еще не самое большое из зол